# Software versioning - MS patterns and Practices

Tags: build, versioning, software-distribution

I am reading the build process article from MS patterns and pratices team http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817676.aspx

They recommend using the pattern **major version . minor version . build number . revision** in the AssemblyInfo file.

i understand how and when to update major version and minor version and assuming i have a CI build server which can increment build numbers on successful builds. However, I dont quite understand under what circumstances one should consider incrementing revision numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revision numbers are used to track builds within a given major & minor version.
 Usually you ship to the customer a given major & minor version
(In MS-terms "Windows XP" would be the major version, "SP3" would be the minor version.)
In order to give any hotfix to the customer within your given major & minor combination you would have to count up the revision.
[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) might also be a good read on the topic